# Both with the same name

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, riddle

Who is the only person in *Tanach* whose father and father-in-law are two different people and have the exact same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noah. Both his father and father-in-law were named "Lemech".

Comment: Only according to those who hold that Noach married Na'amoh bas Lomech.

Answer (score 3):

Did the *sh'vatim* marry their half-sisters? What about *Kayin* and *Hevel*?

Comment: Good points if you hold like those opinions. This is an appropriate comment on the question so it should be posted as such.

Comment: Isn't it also an answer?

Comment: I meant it as an answer, yes.

Comment: My friend reminded me how he asked the riddle and msh210's answer is not acceptable anymore.